# past vs a longer past

Tags: tense

The platform was built in the past (say 1 week ago), and project was developed in a longer past (say 1 year ago), is the following usage of tenses correct:

> The platform that we eventually built did not exist when I developed the projects.

Comment: No, we do not have the idea of past and longer past. There are merely two things in the simple past.

Comment: Although the grammar in your question is far from correct, I think I know what you mean and your actual sentence is fine.

Comment: @stevekeiretsu The grammar is absolutely fine. He might want to take out the "that".

Comment: @Lambie when I commented the question said something like "The platform that we eventually happened".

Comment: @stevekeiretsu I see. Thanks.

Comment: "The platform that we eventually built did not exist when I developed the projects." is perfectly fine grammar, ignore comments above that say it is not.

Answer (score 1):

> "The platform that we eventually built did not exist when I developed
> the projects."

This is correct grammar and use and is completely clear.

If in the context of the speech, "the platform" is already determined (this means a listener would know which "platform" you meant), you should consider leaving out the determiner "that we eventually built", and just say "**The platform did not exist when I developed the projects.**".

If the platform is determined by context and you still wish to emphasis that you built it:  "**The platform, which we eventually built, did not exist when I developed the projects.**"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the simplest option which gives a sense of time order is

> After developing the project we built the platform.

There is no question that both actions took place in the past and one followed the other.

Of course

> Last year we developed the project, last week we built the platform.

also works, but that's too easy